# pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class '__main__.Title'>: attribute lookup Title on __main__ failed

Tags: python, pickle

pickle is not able dump data in file . What am I doing wrong ?    The error says that attribute of class on **main** failed. I have checked internet but not much clarity. The code is as followed

```py
import pickle


class Title:
    def __init__(self, title, platform, size, price):
        self.title = title
        self.platform = platform
        self.size = size
        self.price = price

    def display(self):
        print("Printing the title details", '\n')
        print('TITLE:{} , PLATFORM:{}, SIZE:{} , PRICE:{}'
              .format(self.title, self.platform, self.size, self.price))


g = Title("Battlefield V", "Steam", "65GB", "1200")

""" Serialisation to be done of the instance g using pickle module"""

with open('game.csv', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(g, f)
print('serialization is complete - file object created')

with open('game.ser', 'rb') as f:
    game_obj = pickle.load(f)
print('Deserialization is complete - python obj created')

game_obj.display()
```

The error message is as follows:

```
pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class '__main__.Title'>: attribute lookup      Title on __main__ failed
```

Comment: @Roman sorry for typo , I have tried various extensions and they got mixed up . I am still getting the same error . The error message is still same .                                                                _pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class '__main__.Title'>: attribute lookup Title on __main__ failed

Comment: It works here well, I don't see any obvious error. Try it on different computer, you can also provide us your python version. You can see it in the intro banner in the Python interpreter.

Comment: Are you using Pycharm?

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in the file name, pickled file is named differently than the one you attempt to unpickle, otherwise it works as it is supposed in both Python 3.7.3 and 2.7.16 when the name is fixed:

```bash
$ python3 test.py 
serialization is complete - file object created
Deserialization is complete - python obj created
Printing the title details 

TITLE:Battlefield V , PLATFORM:Steam, SIZE:65GB , PRICE:1200
$ python2 test.py 
serialization is complete - file object created
Deserialization is complete - python obj created
('Printing the title details', '\n')
TITLE:Battlefield V , PLATFORM:Steam, SIZE:65GB , PRICE:1200
```

Even your original code have different error message:

```
$ python3 test.py 
serialization is complete - file object created
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 27, in <module>
    with open('game.ser', 'rb') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'game.ser'
```

It seems that your sample code does not have a problem that you originally encountered in some larger application.